Is the functor from varieties to topological spaces faithful?
$\def\O{\mathcal{O}} \def\Var\{\mathrm{\bf Var}} \def\Aff{\mathrm{\bf Aff}} \def\A{\mathbb{A}} \def\F\{\mathcal{F}} \def\G{\mathcal{G}} \def\Top{\mathrm{\bf Top}}$Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Let us define a variety as a locally ringed space that admits a finite open cover such that each open thereof is isomorphic (as a locally ringed space) to an affine algebraic set with its sheaf of regular functions.
A morphism between varieties $(X, \F)$ and $(Y, \G)$ is defined as a morphism of locally ringed spaces, which is a pair $(f, f^\#)$ where $f: X \to Y$ is a topological morphism and $f^\#: \G \to f_*\F$ is a morphism of sheaves of local rings (sending maximal to maximal in stalks).
So we get a category $\Var$ which is a full subcategory of the category of locally ringed spaces.
Define the category $\Aff$ of affine algebraic sets, where the morphisms between two algebraic sets $A \subseteq \A^n$ to $B \subseteq \A^m$ is given coordinate-wise by a polynomial in $n$ variables.
In my course we have seen a theorem that says that the following functor is full:
$$
\begin{aligned}
  \Aff &\longrightarrow \Var \\
  A    &\longmapsto  (A, \O_A) \\
 f\downarrow &\longmapsto \ \downarrow (f, f^*) \\
 B &\longmapsto (B, \O_B)
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\O_A$ denotes the sheaf of regular functions, and $f^*$ denotes the sheaf morphism where $f^*_U: \O_A(U) \to \O_B(f^{-1}(U))$ is given by $s \mapsto s \circ f$.
In particular, the morphism of sheaves part $f^\#$ of a morphism of affine varieties is determined by the topological morphism $f$, so, to give such a morphism it suffices to give the topological map between the varieties (provided it satisfies the required properties, i.e. being componentwise a polynomial).
In other words, the forgetful fucntor $\Aff \to \Top$ is faithful.
I'm confused about the general case: if $(X, \O_X)$ and $(Y, \O_Y)$ are arbitrary varieties, is it true that for any morphism $(f, f^\#)$ between them, then $f^\#$ is determined by $f$ as $s \mapsto s \circ f$ locally everywhere? In other words, is the forgetful functor $\Var \to \Top$ faithful? (So in particular $\Var$ would be a concrete category.)
The thing that bothers me is that in the affine case, the sheaf is just the sheaf of regular functions, so a section is indeed a function that we can compose with $f$. But in the general case, I don't see how $s \circ f$ makes any sense.

Yes! Except the definition is mildly inaccurate. You really should be working with sheaves of local $k$-algebras instead of plain local rings to obtain the theory of $k$-varieties. Equivalently, you want to work in the slice of the category of locally ringed spaces over $\mathrm{Spec}(k)$. To illustrate this, $\mathrm{Spec}(k)$ corresponds to the $k$-affine algebraic set that consists of a single point. This should not have any automorphisms, but the automorphisms of $\mathrm{Spec}(k)$ as a locally ringed space are the field automorphisms of $k$, of which there are uncountably many!
First, let $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ be any locally ringed space. For any point $x\in U\subseteq X$ and section $s\in\mathcal{O}_X(U)$, we can 'evaluate $s$ at $x$' by considering the image of $s$ in the residue field $\kappa(x)=\mathcal{O}_{X,x}/\mathfrak{m}_{X,x}$. For a morphism $(f,f^{\#})\colon(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\rightarrow(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)$ of locally ringed spaces, locality means that we obtain a field homomorphism $\kappa(f(x))\rightarrow\kappa(x)$ for any $x\in X$ and this takes the value of a section $s\in\mathcal{O}_Y(V)$ at $f(x)\in V$ to the value of the section $f^{\#}(s)$ at $x\in f^{-1}(V)$. It is in this sense that the sections of locally ringed spaces 'behave like' functions.
Now, if $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is a $k$-variety, much more is true. Indeed, $\kappa(x)$ is a $k$-algebra by definition and finitely generated as such (this is because the residue field is a local invariant and it's true for an affine algebraic set), hence equal to $k$ by the assumption of algebraic closure. Thus, we can canonically identify $\kappa(x)=k$ for any $x\in X$. This yields a map of sheaves (of sets) from $\mathcal{O}_X$ to the sheaf $k_X$ (non-standard notation) of $k$-valued functions on $X$. In the case of a map $(f,f^{\#})\colon(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\rightarrow(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)$, the induced map $\kappa(f(x))\rightarrow\kappa(x)$ for any $x\in X$ now reduces to the identity, yielding the suggestive formula $(f^{\#}(s))(x)=s(f(x))$ for any section $s\in\mathcal{O}_Y(V)$ with $f(x)\in V$. In other words, there is a commutative diagram of sheaves
\begin{equation*}
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathcal{O}_Y @>>> k_Y\\
@V{f^{\#}}VV @V{f^{\ast}}VV\\
\mathcal{O}_X @>>> f_{\ast}k_X,
\end{CD}
\end{equation*}
where the right vertical map is simply given by pulling back along $f$. In particular, it is determined by $f$, so to verify faithfulness, it remains to prove that the horizontal maps are monomorphisms. However, a monomorphism of sheaves is detected locally and the property holds locally because it is true for affine algebraic sets by definition.

If I understood correctly then, with the definition I gave above, $f$ does not determine $f^#$? A counterexample being what you mentioned about the one-point variety, the identity as a topological map + an automorphism of $k$. (I'm insisting on that definition just because it's the one I have to work with in the course I'm doing.)

@Anakhand Unfortunately, I have to insist on changing the definition. If you were given this definition in a course, it was an error. Indeed, as we noted, the affine algebraic set ${0}$ does not have non-trivial automorphisms, but the locally ringed space $({0},\underline{k})$ does. This proves that the functor $\mathbf{Var}\rightarrow\mathbf{Top}$ is not faithful if we adopt your original conventions, but it also implies that the functor $\mathbf{Aff}\rightarrow\mathbf{Var}$ is not full under those conventions, yet that was something you wanted to be true.

I was about to go point this out to my professor but fortunately I read the definition he gave again. Indeed, locally ringed spaces are defined with sheaves of local $k$-algebras, not any local rings. In my head "locally ringed" meant, well... "with local rings". IMO that's just some bad terminology.

@Anakhand Yeah, that's potentially misleading, but I'm glad the misunderstanding is worked out now.

Even the category of all ringed spaces is concrete, see MO/2015, but of course you can't just talk the usual points to produce the forgetful functor; see the answer by Zhen Lin for details.
